# Como saber a diferença entre uma array e outra?

Tags: ionic, typescript

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Show } from "./shows/show";
// import { SHOWS, DISPLAYING_SHOWS } from './shows/shows';

export const SHOWS: Show[] = [
  {
    name: "Arrow",
    seasons: [
      {
        seasonNumber: 1,
        episodes: [
          {
            numberInShow: 0o1,
            seasonNumber: 0o1,
            numberInSeason: 0o1,
            episodeName: "Pilot",
            watched: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        seasonNumber: 2,
        episodes: [
          {
            numberInShow: 24,
            seasonNumber: 0o2,
            numberInSeason: 0o1,
            episodeName: "Episode",
            watched: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

export const DISPLAYING_SHOWS: Show[] = [];

export let REST_SHOWS: any[] = [];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ShowService {
  constructor() {
    // let r: any[] = [];
    let s: any[] = [];
    let d: any[] = [];

    for (const show of SHOWS) {
      s.push(show.name);
    }

    for (const show of DISPLAYING_SHOWS) {
      d.push(show.name);
    }

    // for (let index = 0; index < s.length; index++) {
    //   if (d.includes(s[index])) r.push(s[index]);
    // } // old, mas com preguiça

    // REST_SHOWS = r;
    REST_SHOWS = REST_SHOWS.filter(x => !s.includes(d));
  }

  getDisplayingShows(): Show[] {
    return DISPLAYING_SHOWS;
  }

  addShow(show: Show) {
    DISPLAYING_SHOWS.push(show);
    REST_SHOWS.splice(REST_SHOWS.indexOf(show.name), 1);
  }

  deleteShow(show: Show) {
    // const key = undefined;
    // for (const s of DISPLAYING_SHOWS) {
    //   const index = DISPLAYING_SHOWS.indexOf(s);
    //   DISPLAYING_SHOWS.splice(index, 1);
    // }
    REST_SHOWS.push(show.name);
    DISPLAYING_SHOWS.splice(
      DISPLAYING_SHOWS.indexOf(this.getDisplayingShow(show.name)),
      1
    );
  }

  getDisplayingShow(name: string) {
    for (const s of DISPLAYING_SHOWS) {
      if (s.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) return s;
    }
    return null;
  }

  isDisplaying(name: string) {
    return this.getDisplayingShow(name) !== null; // !== null === true; === null === false
  }

  isShowDisplaying(show: Show) {
    return DISPLAYING_SHOWS.includes(show);
  }

  updateShow(show: Show) {
    this.deleteShow(show);
    this.addShow(show);
  }

  // Database
  getRestShows(): Show[] {
    let rest: Show[] = [];
    for (const r of REST_SHOWS) {
      rest.push(this.getShow(r));
    }
    return rest;
  }

  getShows(): Show[] {
    return SHOWS;
  }

  getShow(name: string) {
    for (const show of SHOWS) {
      if (show.name === name) return show;
    }
    return null;
  }

  getShowByClass(show: Show) {
    for (const s of SHOWS) {
      if (s.name === show.name) return s;
    }
    return null;
  }

  existsShow(name: string) {
    return this.getShow(name) !== null;
  }
}
```

Eu quero pegar os shows que não estão em DISPLAYING_SHOWS, como se fosse uma subtração:

shows - displaying_shows = rest;

Sempre quando eu deleto alguma coisa do displaying_shows, o rest continua com o mesmo valor de antes.

Não ocorre nenhum erro no console.

Comment: Se poderia explicar colocando dois `arrays` e um `array` resultante? não precisa colocar assim... (Observação: que nomenclaturas de nomes são essas, não tem padrão?). Tem mais problemas, do que somente o que está na pergunta!.

Comment: ... é como eu disse coloca dois `array` e o `array` do resultado, que podemos ajudar... (realmente a subtração não ficou clara para mim pelo menos)